# the code is giving me a number from the list instead of the mode

Tags: python

in one of my work i need to find the mode a list called "dataset" using no modual or function that would find the mode by itself.
i tried to make it so it can output the mode or the list of modes depending on the list of numbers. I used 2 for loops so the first number of the list checks each number of the list including its self to see how many numbers of its self there is, for example if my list was 123415 it would say there is 2 ones, and it does this for all the numbers of the list. the number with the most counts would be the mode. The bottom section of the code where the if elif and else is, there is where it checks if the number has the most counts by comparing with the other numbers of the list checking if it has more numbers or the same as the previous biggest number.

I've tried to change the order of the codes but i'm still confused why it is doing this error

```
    pop_number = []
    pop_amount = 0
    amount = 0
    for i in range(len(dataset)):    
        for x in dataset:
            if dataset[i] == x:
                amount += 1
            if amount>pop_amount:
                pop_amount = amount
                pop_number = []
                pop_number.append(x)
                amount = 0
            elif amount==pop_amount:
                pop_amount = amount
                if x not in pop_number:
                    pop_number.append(x)
                    pop_amount = amount
                    amount = 0
            else:
                continue            

    print(pop_number)
```

i expected the output to be the mode of the list or the list of modes but it came up with the last number from the list

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how you expect this code to produce the mode of the list? Why are there two `for` loops and how do they relate?

Comment: From my initial read, it appears that `amount` and therefore `pop_amount` will only ever equal 1 or 0, since you only ever add 1 and reset to 0. Is that the intended behavior? FWIW, this would be a great use-case for a dictionary instead of a list, or at the very least `list.count()`, which doesn't make use of external modules

Comment: `elif amount==pop_amount: pop_amount = amount` What is the purpose here?  They're already equal.  Why bother setting them equal again?

Comment: @tripleee i used 2 for loops so the first number of the list checks each number of the list including its self to see how many numbers of its self there is for example if my list was 123415 it would say there is 2 ones and it does this for all the numbers of the list. the number with the most counts would be the mode. in the bottom section of the code where the if elif and else is, there is where it checks if the number has the most counts by comparing with the other numbers of the list checking if it has more numbers or the same as the previous biggest number.

Comment: Probably [edit] your question to include this explanation, perhaps with the punctuation cleaned up.

Comment: `pop_number = []; pop_number.append(x)` is a pretty roundabout way of saying `pop_number = [x]`

Comment: If the list contains the same number twice, you end up finding the second when you see the first, and then counting the first (and the second) again when you see the second. Going over the entire list every time is going to be extremely inefficient anyway; a better solution might be to only examine items later in the list than the current item to avoid comparing A to B and then B to A.

Comment: Resetting `amount` to 0 when you just incremented it is definitely a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is apparently homework, I will present a sketch, not working code.

Observe that a `dict` in Python can hold key-value mappings.

Let the numbers in the input list be the keys, and the values the number of times they occur. Going over the list, use each item as the key for the dict, and add one to the value (starting at 0 -- [`defaultdict(int)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is good for this). If the result is bigger than any previous maximum, remember this key.
Since you want to allow for more than one mode value, the variable which remembers the maximum key should be a list; but since you have a new maximum, replace the old list with a list containing just this key. If another value also reaches the maximum, add it to the list. (That's the `append` method.)

(See how this is `if` *bigger than maximum so far* and then `else if` *equal to maximum so far* and then otherwise there is no need to do anything.)

When you have looped over all items in the input list, the list of remembered keys is your result.

Go back and think about what variables you need already before the loop. The maximum so far should be defined but guaranteed to be smaller than any value you will see -- it makes sense to start this at `0` because as soon as you see one key, it will have a bigger count than zero.  And the keys you want to remember can start out as an empty list.

Now think about how you would test this. What happens if the input list is empty? What happens if the input list contains just the same number over and over? What happens if every item on the input list is unique? Can you think of other corner cases?

Answer (score 0):

Without using any module or function that will specifically find the mode itself, you can do that with much less code. Your code will work with a little more effort, I highly suggest you to try to solve the problem on your own logic, but meanwhile let me show you how to take the help of all the built-in data structures in Python List, Tuples, Dictionaries and Sets within 7-8 lines. Also there is unzipping at the end (*). I will suggest you to look these up, when you get time.

```
lst = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,2,2,2,5,5,6]
# finds the unique elements
unique_elems = set(lst)
# creates a dictionary with the unique elems as keys and initializes the values to 0
count = dict.fromkeys(unique_elems,0)
# gets the frequency of each element in the lst
for elem in unique_elems:
  count[elem] = lst.count(elem)
# finds max frequency
max_freq = max(count.values())
# stores list of mode(s)
modes = [i for i in count if count[i] == max_freq]
# prints mode(s), I have used unzipping here so that in case there is one mode,
# you don't have to print ugly [x]
print(*modes)
```

Or if you want to go for the shortest (I really shouldn't be making such bold claims in StackOverflow), then I guess this will be it (even though, writing short codes for the sake of it is discouraged)

```
lst = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,2,2,2,5,5,6]
freq_dist = [(i, lst.count(i)) for i in set(lst)]
[print(i,end=' ') for i,j in freq_dist if j==max(freq_dist, key=lambda x:x[1])[1]]
```

And if you just want to go bonkers and say goodbye to loops (Goes without saying, this is ugly, really ugly):

```
lst = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,2,2,2,5,5,6]
unique_elems = set(lst)
freq_dist = list(map(lambda x:(x, lst.count(x)), unique_elems))
print(*list(map(lambda x:x[0] if x[1] == max(freq_dist,key = lambda y: y[1])[1] else '', freq_dist)))
```

Comment: You are traversing the same list over and over. This will be inefficient for large input lists. Why not just `count = dict(); for x in lst: if x not in count: count[x] = 1; else : count[x] += 1` which of course can be simplified still if you allow `defaultdict`. And then of course you can find the `max` whilst building the dict instead of immediately traversing it again.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just wanted to use all the data structures and show their usage. The code could have been even shorter, let me update.